# End word is hidden in algorithm block

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

Suppose that i have this code:

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{dcocument}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\end{dcocument}
```

Result:

[image]

Where are `end` words?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `vlined` option suppresses the printing of “end”. Just remove the option, keeping just `ruled`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{How to write algorithms}
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]